# C言語でオブジェクト指向は可能?

Tags: ruby, c

ぱっと調べた感じ構造体という言葉が出てきましたがよくわかりませんでした。

例えば以下のRubyのコードをCで表現するとどうなりますか?

```
class HogeModule
  def hoge 
  end
end

class HogeClass
  include HogeModule

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

class FugaClass < HogeClass

  def initalize(name)
    super
  end

  def fuga
    p @name
  end

  def self.fuga
    p '@name'
  end
end

FugaClass.fuga

fuga = FugaClass.new
fuga.fuga
```

Comment: Ruby 2.4.1p111 だと，`class HogeClass` の定義の中で，モジュールではなくクラスに対して `include` していることに関するエラー `TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)` が出ます．サンプルコードを間違えていませんか？

Answer (score 2):

> 例えば以下のRubyのコードをCで表現するとどうなりますか?

C言語はそういう言語ではありませんが、敢えてこの質問に答えるとこうなります。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
} HogeModule;

void
HogeModule_hoge(HogeModule *hm) {
}

typedef struct {
  const char* name;
  HogeModule *base;
} HogeClass;

void
HogeClass_initialize(HogeClass *hc, const char* name) {
  hc->base = malloc(sizeof(HogeModule));
  hc->name = name;
}

typedef struct {
  HogeClass *base;
} FugaClass;

void
FugaClass_initialize(FugaClass *fc) {
  fc->base = malloc(sizeof(HogeClass));
  HogeClass_initialize(fc->base, "");
}

void
FugaClass_static_fuga() {
}

void
FugaClass_fuga(FugaClass *fc) {
  puts(fc->base->name);
}


int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  FugaClass fc;

  FugaClass_static_fuga();

  FugaClass_initialize(&fc);
  FugaClass_fuga(&fc);
  return 0;
}
```

メモリの解放、NULL 判定などは割愛の為あえて行っていません。

Comment: ちなみに言っておくと fuga.fuga の様に . で呼び出せるからオブジェクト指向だ、等という物はないです。

Comment: Classメソッドを関数ポインタで構造体に定義 / new関数で関数ポインタに関数を代入　とすることで、メソッドのカプセル化およびインスタンス化のような概念が可能になります。応用でポリモーフィズムも可能になります。かつてのBrew/Cがそのような思想になっていました。

Comment: そうですね。これ以上書くモチベーション無いですが、似せたものは作れるでしょうね。

Answer (score 0):

目的の回答にそぐわないものとなりますし、コードを書く事もできません、が
オブジェクト指向とC言語について説明させてもらいます。
簡潔にいうと、Cの構造体に似ており、
Cでは構造体というものを用いてプログラムを書く事が出来ますが、
オブジェクト指向は言語すべてが構造体でできているようなものです。
なので、Cで書くとどのようになるか、は他の方と同じようなコードができますし、オブジェクト指向はC言語では関数と構造体を多用すれば実装することが見かけ上可能です。